# Create a different pivot view in Power Query

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

I have the data structured in excel in the following format

[image]

What I want to do with that is to transform it into this. In simple words for each ID I want to record the difference in value from previous day, and if there is no value in previous day we just keep the current value.

[image]

As an intermediate step I am trying to transform the raw data into something like this but I am not sure how to go about it in simple Excel pivot tables, or Power query transformations.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with your sample because [v1-v2] is not the same method as [v5-v4, v3-v2, v8-v7] but I assume the latter ones were right

See if this works for you

Assumes data in 3 columns in a range named **Table1** with column headers **Dates, ID, Value**

You can paste into PowerQuery using ... Advanced Editor ...

Creates a column with the value of yesterday for that ID and returns a null if nothing is found. Then does the subtraction, and pivots

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Dates", type date}, {"ID", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
Yesterday = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type" , "Yesterday", (i) => List.Sum(Table.SelectRows( #"Changed Type", each ([ID] = i[ID] and Date.AddDays([Dates],1) = i[Dates]))[Value]), type number ),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Yesterday,null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Yesterday"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Custom", each [Value]-[Yesterday]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Value", "Yesterday"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Dates", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Dates", type text}}, "en-US")[Dates]), "Dates", "Custom", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```